# markdown のコードラインの中で ` (バッククオート) を使うには？

Tags: markdown

タイトルのようにmarkdownの中で ` を使いたいです。

GithubのWikiの中でmarkdownを使っています、

試したこと：

- \`
- `

出来ませんでしたので、教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: 回答したようにGitHubのWikiの中でのマークダウンではバックスラッシュエスケープができるはずです。問題を他の人が再現してみることができるよう、期待どおりにならなかったテキスト（コード）を示してください。

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko さん、編集履歴を見てみると分かりますが、バックスラッシュという言葉が入ったのは質問者さんの意図ではありません。シンプルなうっかりミスと思われます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、それについてはコメントから消されているので今そう書かれても第三者には何のことかわからないと思います。

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko 編集履歴は "編集日時" となっている部分のリンクをクリックすることで確認できます。 / タイトルは分かりやすくなるようにと編集したつもりでしたが、nekketsuuu さんの指摘通り私のうっかりミスで逆に混乱させてしまったようで申し訳ないです。

Comment: 編集履歴は見ましたよ。でも私は質問の編集の要約を記しただけであってミスが質問者の意図かどうかは関係ありません。そしてその私のコメントは消えている（自分で消した覚えはないので消された？）ので、今更その指摘をここに書かれても第三者には何のことかわからないでしょう。

Comment: 質問者へ。コードラインとはコードブロックのことですか？

Comment: 質問の内容が修正されず、課題が曖昧なままであるため、質問の評価を下げました。

Comment: そこまで深い問題ではないと思いますが、GithubのWikiにMDで書く時はどうやって`を表示するかを聞きたかっただけです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

コードブロックではなく、インラインコードを指しているものとして回答します。

---

このような場合、前後を **バッククォート2つ** (と念のため半角スペース) で括ってみて下さい。

##### 例

**入力:**
``` `` ` `` ```

**結果:**
`` ` ``

以降、「バッククォート2つ」を表示したい場合には前後を "バッククォート3つ" のように増やしていきます。

**参考:**
[How do I escape a backtick ` within in-line code in Markdown? - Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82718)

Comment: ありがとう御座います。

Comment: なんだろうこの姑息な編集

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko さん、スタック・オーバーフローの投稿はお互いに良くし合う目的で wiki のように編集出来るようになっています。間違いがあれば後から編集するのは通常のフローです。あわせて、スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範も今一度ご確認くださいませ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: バッククオートよりもバッククォートがより正しいとは思えないのだが、もしそう考えて編集したというのなら、なぜ質問のタイトルもあわせて編集しないのか。おかしいでしょう。

Comment: 質問文と回答文とで必ずしも語彙を揃えないといけないわけでもないですし、自分の回答を自分の好む語法に合わせて微修正するのは自然に思います。

Comment: それを自然と見るか勝手と見るかで違いますね。

Comment: @Itagaki Fumihiko せっかくの提案を破棄した上で私が編集していたのであればズルのような印象を持たれるのも分かりますが、今回の編集提案は (私自身が) 受け入れているので、決して貢献を蔑ろにしたわけではありません (Itagaki さんの信用度もわずかにプラスされているはずです)。 / 一方で、私も英語に絶対の自信はないものの、個人的には「クォート」の方が収まりがよいので微調整を加えました。自分の投稿が編集されると通知がくるので気づいたまでで、タイトルは見落としていました。

Comment: クオートをクォートに変える合理的な理由は私にはわかりませんね。

Answer (score 1):

マークダウンには多くの方言があるのですが、質問はGitHubの話ですね。

GitHubのマークダウンはバックスラッシュエスケープ可能なはずです。

https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash

これはGitHub Docsでも解説されています。

> **Markdown のフォーマットの無視**
>
> ---
>
> You can tell GitHub to ignore (or escape) Markdown
> formatting by using `\` before the Markdown character.

[Markdown のフォーマットの無視](https://docs.github.com/ja/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#ignoring-markdown-formatting)

Comment: 投票行動に納得がいかないなあ。どういう見識でこの回答にマイナス票を入れられるのか。

Comment: 多くの Markdown 処理系において、コードブロックやインラインコードの中ではバックスラッシュエスケープは使えないのではないでしょうか。特に GitHub Flavored Markdown 0.29-gfm では使えないです。タイトルにあるように質問者さんはコードの中でバッククォートを使いたいようです。

Comment: バックスラッシュ使えなかったなら使えなかったコードを示してくださいと私は質問者にコメントしています。そうでなければ良いリソースにはならないでしょう。それから nettetsu さんの指摘はこの回答のマイナス投票の理由を想像で代弁しているのですか？もしくはマイナス票の投票者本人なのですか？

Comment: 質問文とこちらの回答とを見比べてコメントしたまでです。質問者さんはタイトルでコードの中でバックティックを使いたいと述べてらして、質問文の中でバックスラッシュエスケープを使ってもできなかったとおっしゃっているので、こちらの回答だと不十分なのは類推できるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: あなたは GitHub Flavored Markdown 0.29-gfm を調べて知見を得たのならそれを詳しく書くべきです。それがより良いリソースとなるのではないですか。

Comment: 私が知っていることをまとめると cubick さんの回答とほとんど同じ内容になりそうで、新規性は特に無いですね……。

Comment: 出典くらい示せるでしょう。